# Mapping by gmapping isn't correct

Tags: ros, navigation, laser, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm doing the mapping process by gmapping. At the beginning, my robot can recognize a wall very well, but when i spin the robot and face into empty space, it suddenly appears a line on the map in Rviz, although there is nothing there. What's the problem? Is there any parameter in gmapping launch file I should adjust?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387835/mapping-by-gmapping-isn%27t-correct/) by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2021-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-10-03**:
Please edit your description to provide more information. Which gmapping package are you using (give us a link)? What sensor input is your robot using to generate a current pose?

You can edit your question using the "edit" button at the end of your description.

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-10-03**:
Oh, I have solved the problem, but thanks for your reply, I will close the answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-05**:
@Kevin1719: we're really happy you solved your problem, but we're less happy you didn't take 5 minutes to post an answer so future readers of your question who might be struggling with the same problem could benefit from what you found out.

If everyone on ROS Answers would only post "oh I figured it out" but then not explain *what* they figured out, there would be no point in having this forum here (as there would be no usable information on it).

Please take the time to do that and post what you did as an answer. Then accept your own answer.

**Comment by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) on 2021-10-05**:
Yes, thank you for reminding me :)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-05**:
Please don't close questions if/once they've been answered.

Accepting the answer suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved: the problem was caused because I set the joint xyz attribute too low and it seem to be inside the robot, so the laser beams couldn't get through the robot chassis and were looking strange. Setting it higher, above the base link solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin1719](https://answers.ros.org/users/86013/kevin1719/) with karma: 58 on 2021-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0